# Are questions about different editions of a book on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

*I am going to link this to an [example question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2425/what-are-the-major-differences-between-the-movie-tie-in-edition-of-arthur-spide) on the site, if the consensus is that it is off-topic I will remove the example question.*

Are questions about differences between editions (in reason) on topic?

For instance: Does the first edition of <*book*> by <*author*> contain a different epilogue to the current edition?

Or: Was the first edition of <*book*> really illustrated by the author?

Comment: I am more curious about what leads you to believe they might _not_ be on topic. Is that something you think you could summarize and maybe edit into your question?

Comment: I don't see why *not*. As @Emrakul said above, do you have any reason to think that they might be off topic?

Comment: @Emrakul I was worried people might have found this nit-picking (which is why I added the (in reason)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, go for it. Those questions match my definition of "Literature," and I've wanted to ask a few of those questions myself. Your question has several upvotes at the moment, including mine, and doesn't seem to be in danger of closing a few hours after being asked.

Two moderators [have](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/703/are-questions-about-different-editions-of-a-book-on-topic#comment2492_703) already [commented](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/703/are-questions-about-different-editions-of-a-book-on-topic#comment2493_703) that they don't see why this shouldn't be squarely on-topic, for whatever that's worth.